# Black background shows up at the right side of the screen when viewing the page with resized screen

Tags: css, layout

I have search all over the internet and tried for hours to resolve the issue with no avail!

Visit http://testdrupal.ml/node/126 on your mobile device or from your desktop but with resized window to any size... and you will notice a black background will show up at the right side of the screen.

I have tried for hours to play with css and yet the problem not solved!

Can someone please point me to the right css style to be used in order to make this black background disappear ?

**Using:**

- Drupal 8.6.10
- Default Bartik theme

[An image showing the black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Psze.png)

**I want to provide the full css code but the project is private and I can only provide full information with website access in a private chat... I hope someone will be intereste**d!

Comment: you have this margin doing that body.layout-no-sidebars.path-node.page-node-type-article {
    margin: 15px;
}

Comment: Have you changed something? I no longer see the issue in Firefox 65.0.1/Mac

Comment: Have you been able to isolate the relevant CSS and HTML?

Comment: @AndyHoffman No, I changed nothing, I can still see it on chorme/IE and from android browser.

Comment: @godfather I can't see the {margin: 15px} you mentioned!

Comment: I want to provide the full css code but the project is private and I can only provide full information with website access in a private chat... I hope someone will be interested!